# Relation between the eigenvalue density and the resolvent

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, random-matrices

Many texts (e.g. [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1275)-[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0046)-[3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1275)) on random matrices start with some variation of the identity:

$$\rho_1(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{Im}\{\langle\text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}-\lambda\mathbf{I})^{-1}\rangle\}$$

where the brakets denote the average over the ensemble of eigvenvalues and 'Tr' is the trace of the *resolvant* matrix $(\mathbf{X}-\lambda\mathbf{I})^{-1}$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$. The left side is the 1 point correlation function, i.e. the density, which is also defined as

$$\rho_1(\lambda)= \big\langle\sum_i \delta(\lambda-\lambda_i)\big\rangle $$

(same ensemble). How does one prove the above identity?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided a partial proof on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/150808/41373), and [Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11260/carlo-beenakker)   [corrected](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150813/41373) some mistakes related to complex integration and clashing definitions of the marginal probability density. I consider this question answered.